# Rails 4 - Devise with nested forms - fields_for :symbol issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise, nested-forms

I'm trying create a user using devise, and I want to create a business_detail on sign_up (one to one relationship).

I have the following relationships inside the models.

**user.rb**

```
has_one :business_detail, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :business_detail
```

**business_detail.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

Inside the form I've used the following code:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :business_detail do |b|
```

The issue here is that the form is not being rendered, unless I use plural form (`:business_details`)

If I use this, I won't be able to create the object, since the model is named on singular, and I can't pass the object on fields_for because then I won't be able to create the object using devise create.

in **registrations_controller** I've added:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :business, :name, :occupation, :gender, business_detail: [:city, :industry, :postcode, :photo, :phone])
  end
end
```

If I use plural form (inside the form and inside the **configure_permitted_parameters** method) the params looks like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uH5axM94yiKH5rbVaAyZHzlHD6zoErSPkR5y7wAURhA=", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "password"=>"12345567", "password_confirmation"=>"123123", "business"=>"1", "business_details"=>{"address_line_1"=>"", "address_line_2"=>"", "city"=>"", "country"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "industry"=>"", "phone"=>""}, "email"=>"asdasdasd@aa.a"}, "commit"=>"Create Business Account", "controller"=>"registrations", "action"=>"business_create", "format"=>"user"}
```

and the hash inside devise's **build_resource** method is

```
{"email"=>"asdasdasd@aa.a", "password"=>"12345567", "password_confirmation"=>"123123", "business"=>"1", "name"=>"", "business_details"=>{"city"=>"", "industry"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "phone"=>""}}
```

So, I'm thinking that sending the symbol using singular form would solve my issue.

I've tried adding the model to the inflections list inside **config/initializers/inflections.rb** by:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( business_detail )
end
```

but it did not work.

Anyone suggestions please?

Comment: I'm currently experiencing a similar issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I've added a small hack of which I'm not proud. I've overridden devise's sign_up_params method to add an extra param at the singular form.


def sign_up_params
  params["user"]["business_detail_attribute"] = params["user"]["business_detail_attributes"]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)
end